# Custom angular circular progress bar SVG User Interface

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, progress-bar, drawing

I have developed my circular progress bar from [angular-circular-progress](https://github.com/pistou/angular-circular-progress) github.

My current input was:

[image]

I need to modify the end of the progress bar with a small **CIRCLE** and a **VALUE CENTRE** of the circular progress bar with real animation value based on svg movement. How I can do that? I really need help from you all guys.

My expected output should be:

[image]

My current snippet:

```js
angular.module('myModule', ['angular-circular-progress'])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://pencil.my/assets/js/circularProgress.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myModule">
<circular-progress
      value="80"
      max="100"
      orientation="1"
      radius="100"
      stroke="10"
      base-color="#fff"
      progress-color="#f9991d"
      iterations="100"
      animation="easeInOutCubic"
  ></circular-progress>
  </div>
```

Comment: I glad to see if anyone can modify the existing library that I was used http://pencil.my/assets/js/circularProgress.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at **ProgressBar.js** ?

```
var bar = new ProgressBar.Circle(container, {

    enter code herecolor: '#aaa',
   // This has to be the same size as the maximum width to
   // prevent clipping
   strokeWidth: 4,
   trailWidth: 1,
   easing: 'easeInOut',
   duration: 1400,
   text: {
        autoStyleContainer: false
   },
   from: { color: '#aaa', width: 1 },
   to: { color: '#333', width: 4 },
   // Set default step function for all animate calls
   step: function(state, circle) {
   circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
   circle.path.setAttribute('stroke-width', state.width);

    var value = Math.round(circle.value() * 100);
    if (value === 0) {
    circle.setText(''); 
    } else {
    circle.setText(value);
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/kimmobrunfeldt/72tkyn40/) is a Fiddle

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Not yet. Is it use angular? I developed my project in angular js.

Comment: Well, it's not made with angular but you can use it in your components

Comment: I've seen your fiddle but the changes was stroke width in total. I just need a small circle lead the stroke while animation was taken.

Comment: First, for the stroke width use progressBar.js and get 'circle.value', next for circle, i think you can use a PNG image that, that rotate with 'circle.value's value, (i mean, make a superposition of the animation with a png)

Comment: Can you please show me in snippet? I did not see the result lol..hohoho

Answer (score 0):

Create a group that has a transparent object the size of your circle and has the small circle at one edge, then [rotate](https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-transformations/) that group around its center. The internals of the SVG would look something like

```
<g id="pip" transform="rotate({{360/value}}, 50, 50)">
<!--contents of g-->
</g>
```

This assumes the diameter of the circle is 100.

Comment: Can you please show me in snippet? I did not see the result lol..hohoho

Comment: I'm not sure I can, because the snippet doesn't directly deal with the SVG. If you right-click on the circle and select "Inspect element", you'll see a circle in there of class "base." Next to that, you'd add a group with a transparent circle and your small circle to it. LOL HOHOHO. You're going to have to hand-edit the SVG if you want something this custom HOHO

Comment: I used the library from here http://pencil.my/assets/js/circularProgress.js to make the circle. If I modified it then it would be more difficult to me.

Comment: That is true. It is always more difficult to do something custom than to do what the library does by default. If it is more important to you to have it not be difficult than it is for it to do what you've described above, then you will need to give up on doing that and just go with what the library does.

Comment: I believed there will be a siution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that converts a number from 0 to 100 into the x,y coordinates needed to give the circle object (drawn with canvas tools) a circular path:

```
function drawCircle(percentage, ctx) {
  var angle = percentage / 100.0;

  var xPos = 140 * Math.cos((angle * (2 * Math.PI)) - (Math.PI * .5));
  var yPos = -140 * Math.sin((angle * (2 * Math.PI)) - (Math.PI * .5) );

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc (xPos + 150, 150 - yPos, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

Look at this plunker to see it in action: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/ePMK7DVLB3OH15oUJzr1?p=preview

This takes the number (from 0 to 100), scales it, converts it to radians, then converts the radians to cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Ok..so nice circle... I need to adapt with my code..thanks.